Can I change current Github status (emoji) via REST API?
You can represent your current status on GitHub using emojis. I want to change this status using the REST API. How can I achieve this?
I have confirmed that it is possible to change this status using GraphQL as per the documentation here:
https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/input-objects#changeuserstatusinput

So if you've found relevant documentation, have you tried it?  What happened?  What's your attempt so far?

Try this
curl -X PATCH -H "Authorization: token YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/user \
-d '{
  "status": {
    "emoji": ":smile:",
    "message": "Working from home",
    "availability": "busy"
  }
}'

